# Angular 4 after installing all modules I have errors

Tags: angular, installation

I would like to try and learn angular.
So I have installed it.
(I have used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=g13I7Xy1PtI)

But all "modules" (?) have error... :(
this is the  '`ng -v`' result:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.4
node: 6.11.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: error
@angular/common: error
@angular/compiler: error
@angular/core: error
@angular/forms: error
@angular/http: error
@angular/platform-browser: error
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: error
@angular/router: error
@angular/cli: error
@angular/compiler-cli: error
@angular/language-service: error
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you can explain the exact steps you took before getting this error, that will help. Did you also run `npm install -g @angular/cli` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using something like yarn, package.json controls the packages and dependencies.
Follow https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

The **-g** option installs a package globally - normally for things like CLI, as opposed to in the **node_modules** folder of a specific project.

If you look in package.json, created by quickstart, you will find two arrays **dependencies** and **devDependencies**.

Add the dependencies into the **package.json** using npm command itself.
use `--save` or `--save-dev` flag to add things to relevant section
(If a package relates to something like testing, that isn't required just to run the app, you would append --save-dev).

Have a look at this [semver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) link, to get an appreciation of things like tilde **~** and caret **^** ranges.

Also if you use things like `npm install <package>@latest --save` for each of the packages you list, you should hopefully get a project setup without dependency conflicts.

If someone has a neater way of doing this so you get all the angular libraries at once in a single install command, I'd appreciate that nugget too.

Comment: `@JGFMK` Yarn uses `package.json` the same way npm does, maybe is better to edit your answer to avoid creating confusion.